Solved | Word: Shortcut to Customize Keyboard Window | Equivalent to VBA 'wdDialogToolsCustomizeKeyboard'
I frequently assign shortcuts to different templates, but it's cumbersome to always navigate through "File" > "Options" > "customize ribbon" > "customize keyboard shortcut" to access the Customize Keyboard window.
In a few months, I have a 9-hour exam where I'll only have access to Microsoft Word. Speed is crucial, so I need a quick way to assign shortcuts on-the-fly during the exam.
I've searched extensively in the "all commands" category but couldn't find the corresponding command. However, ChatGPT provided me with a functional macro:
vba
Sub OpenCustomizeKeyboard()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsCustomizeKeyboard).Show
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

This macro works well for daily use. I can save it in Normal.dotm and assign a shortcut to it.
However, I prefer a non-macro solution, especially for my exam. I don't want to write a macro on the spot and debug it under exam stress.
Does anyone know the direct command to access the "Customize Keyboard" window within Word?
Edit:
Solution
Found it
Category > All Commands > ExtraAnpassenTastatur / ExtraCustomizeKeyboard
Screenshot

The command in the Customize the Keyboard Dialog is ToolsCustomizeKeyboard
There was a key in what ChatGPT told you.
You can, of course, assign a keyboard shortcut to that command.
Here is a link to my article on the Microsoft Answers site about Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts in Word.
Many of the commands in Word are named based on the menus that held them in the menu version of Word. Do not use the similar command ToolsCustomizeKeyboardShortcut (which already has a keyboard shortcut).

i followed the key. however, I am using a non-english word version, so I still didn't find the right "lock for the key" ;)
ps thanks for your very interesting article!

I'm not sure what you mean by "lock." Do you mean command name? I can't say for sure but the individual words in the command may be translated: Tools, Customize, Keyboard. You may be able to get Microsoft specific help at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/42/office-word. If you try there, be sure to specify the language you are using and include a link to this post.
